# Laravel environment files for local and production possibly not working as intended?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

In Laravel 4, I'm setting up my local development machine (my laptop) and then I have my production server.

**In my /bootstrap/start.php**

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(array(

'local'      => array('MacBook-Pro-2.local'),
'production' => array('ripken'),

));
```

I then created a **.env.local.php** in my root directory with the following:

```
<?php

return [

// Database Connection Settings
'db_host'     => '127.0.0.1',
'db_name'     => 'censored',
'db_user'     => 'censored',
'db_password' => 'censored'

];
```

That part works.  However, I went to my production server and created the same exact file, called it **.env.production.php** and it doesn't load the variables from that file.  I don't know what made me think to do it but I renamed that file **.env.php** without "production" in the name and it works.

My question therefore is, why wouldn't **.env.production.php** work?  I thought that is what the good folks over at Laravel wanted me to name my various environment files.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Production is the 'default' ruleset, so it is a bit special. Laravel will look for the "base" or "default" rules when loading production, rather than the actual name production.

So you can change

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(array(
'local'      => array('MacBook-Pro-2.local'),
'production' => array('ripken'),
));
```

to

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(array(
'local'      => array('MacBook-Pro-2.local'),    
));
```

That way anything that is not "MacBook-Pro-2.local" is going to be production automatically. Then just use the default `.env.php` for the production settings.

Every other env needs to be explicitly defined - such as **.env.local.php** and **.env.testing.php** etc

Comment: That's great to know.  I couldn't find that in the docs.  Thanks so much!

Comment: That's weird because if I create the .env.php I will get a "redirect loop"

Comment: Thanks for this! Its pretty bad this isnt documented anywhere. You would think that it would either (1) allow for .env.production.php or (2) throw a specific error.

Comment: super. thanks for that tip. +1 on this info getting into the docs!